# Accused of posting commercial spam because of a link to my website as a signature

Tags: discussion, spam, self-promotion, signatures

We are **new** in this community. In our first questions, we've posted some links to our project's website, which were related to the questions. After one user posted [this thread](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271586/what-to-do-with-a-user-who-frequently-spams-so-with-useless-links-to-their-main), we changed our behavior.

Yesterday we wrote [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26397893/count-words-in-a-string-str/26398029#26398029), which had this link as salutation:

> Best regards,
>
> [ncomputers.org](http://ncomputers.org)

The same user, who wrote that thread, commented on our answer:

> Do not put unrelated spam to your answers!

He/she also edited our answer to delete the salutation and probably voted down our answer (Despite that it has the same meaning of the best voted answer).

We want to invite him/her to stop accusing us of posting spam, and to learn the purpose of our project. We tried to send him/her a private message with this purpose, but we didn't find any feature on the site which allows it.

1. Is it possible to send him/her something similar to a private message?
2. Is it allowed to post a salutation to either our project's
   website or our user profile?

Comment: Previously: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271586/what-to-do-with-a-user-who-frequently-spams-so-with-useless-links-to-their-main

Comment: Soooo tempted to edit out the URL at the bottom of this post right now...

Comment: related MSE post: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Comment: The problem isn't so much that your salutation or signature is something of a link, but that it's out of place here to have one *at all*.  If your identify is a key part of your post, work that into the content, ie "as the author of ___ I would recommend ___"

Comment: Wait a second...is this meta post just a sneaky attempt to get us all to visit your website? You almost had me!

Comment: @ChrisStratton Thank you very much for your comment!

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Haha. No! Everyone can visit it or not. We defend the image of our project and want to know what to do, when someone accuses us for something, that we don't do, that's all.

Comment: Is it even allowed for companies to use one user profile for the whole group? Can't find any definitive answer on this. Seems wrong to me.

Comment: @eddie_cat I don't understand your comment. What does companies have to do with this question?

Comment: @ncomputers.org in other words, is it appropriate for an account to represent a company rather than a user. The [ToS](http://stackexchange.com/legal) seems to target an individual, not a group.

Comment: "Subscriber certifies to Stack Exchange that Subscriber is an **individual** (i.e., not a corporate entity) at least 13 years of age."

Comment: @eddie_cat Let's read between the lines. If ncomputers.org is not 13 years old, then the account will be deleted for being underaged. :)

Comment: @KevinB Ah ok, I understand it.

Comment: @ncomputers.org I didn't downvote your answer BTW.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Thank you very much for your time, your answers, your help and for claryfing it! This would be easier if we could send you a private message. We're a new user and think that you were rude with us, we made the mistake to post links with our questions, we've changed our behaviour and disagree with the thread, where you wrote `(commercial) site`, when our project is a non-profit!

Comment: A non-profit where the main content on your site is a giant "Contribute" button? :P

Comment: @eddie_cat Yes! Of course! You're talking of the title page. Inside the site are contributions for computer science :D

Comment: @ncomputers.org Just want to point out that your way of communicating is nice. Thanks for being humble and opening  your problem publicly. This community also needs to learn that when someone is willing to improve, we all must help and contribute in a polite manner. But mostly people will be rude, un-classy and "we-don't-have-time-for-this" kind. Good luck for your future, and don't worry, SO is just a website.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Andrew gave a good answer but there's something I feel needs to be pointed out here.

Quick check list for people posting answers that contain links to their product/project/whatever:

1. Is your product/etc. **directly pertaining** to solving the **problem in the question?**
2. In your answer, do your **explain in detail** how your product/etc could be used to solve the **specific problem** in the question?

If the answer is yes to both, then you can go ahead with the answer **provided that you clearly state the relationship between you and your product/etc.**

If the answer is no to either of the questions above or you do not state your relationship to the project, and I run into your post, chances are I'm going to flag it as spam. It really depends how egregious it is. If the person only forgot to mention the relationship, I may just put a comment to invite them to do so. However, if the answer is "no" to both questions above, then it's insta-flag. (I don't go out of my way to find spam so I have only 20 spam flags on SO, but 20 out of 20 were deemed helpful.)

Answer (score 44):

- No, there is no user-to-user private messaging system on SO.
- Greetings, salutations, signatures, thanks, etc. are all considered noise in questions and answers. They should not be written and will likely be edited out.
- A link to your own site in your user profile is fine.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I'd never imagine, that greetings, salutations, signatures, thanks, etc. are considered noise!

Comment: @ncomputers.org - all your posts are automatically signed by the system. See that "flair" at the bottom right of every post? *That's* your signature.