# Is this library promotion spamming?

Tags: discussion, answers, spam, self-promotion

I just noticed [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A1062529+%5Bunderscore.js%5D+deleted%3A1). They all start with the same sentence:

> An other approach is to use [underscore.aggregate](https://github.com/nicolaspanel/underscore.aggregate) library ([mixin](http://underscorejs.org/#mixin) for underscorejs).

While each of them seems to answer the respective question, it does not use the bare Underscore library but requires an extra add-on for it. I would be fine with that if [the answer contained the sources of the used mixin functions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/256405/1048572), but as it stands this looks like advertising/promotion of a project.

**Are these answers acceptable? What should be done about them, flagging as spam?**

Comment: Yeah, agreed these answers are spamming to promote whatever 3rd party library to solve the problem.

Comment: @Louis: Not to associated to Underscore.js, but to [`underscore.aggregate`](https://github.com/nicolaspanel/underscore.aggregate). The [SO user](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1062529/bali) has the same profile picture as the [project's maintainer](https://github.com/nicolaspanel) on Github. (I didn't check before, but it really looks like *self*-promotion now)

Comment: Ooops. My earlier comment was incorrect. The author of those answers **is** the author of the mixin being promoted. So yes, spam. When someone suggests a library/tool/whatever to solve a problem and they are the author, or a major contributor, they must reveal the affiliation.

Comment: They all were made within days of each other, sometimes to questions asked over a year ago. Yeah, spamming.

Comment: It might not be mean-spirited. Just because he's providing answers using something he developed himself doesn't make that a promotion (it doesn't cost money, it's an open-source project). He might just be trying to be helpful. It sure seems like he took the time to read the questions and didn't post blindly (the day interval also means he didn't just post one answer after another like spam)

Comment: Woo. Looks like meta effect is coming in. Before posting this, all of the answers had a score of 0. Sorry @Bali!

Comment: @yuvi True, it may not be mean spirited but we don't want SO to turn into a platform for people to promote their projects. Especially problematic are those answers that look like it is just someone who happened to find the tool useful but in fact is the author. Biased perhaps? Sometimes I see a post where the user does not disclose the affiliation. If I look in the profile and do not find other instances, I'll edit the post and leave a comment. But when this is repeated behavior...

Comment: @Louis I agree, but maybe there's a middle-path - fix\remove part of the answers and warn the user not to repeat that behavior or something like that. I don't know what the SO moderation norm is for these cases

Comment: @Bergi See also this [similar question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271586/what-to-do-with-a-user-who-frequently-spams-so-with-useless-links-to-their-main) of mine.

Comment: Well, it seems the answers have all been eaten by a grue.

Comment: All of the answers are now gone!

Comment: Looks like someone has flagged them and a moderator took action. At least, [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26752070/1048572) was deleted by @BillTheLizard.

Comment: Flagged several more identical "answers" earlier today. He's still at it.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I saw some flags on this earlier and sent the user a warning after deleting the posts. If there were only one or two posts it would have been fine to just ask in a comment for the user to disclose their affiliation, but since there were a couple dozen answers promoting a project without disclosing affiliation I decided to take stronger action.  Some of the answers were nothing but a link and need a lot of revising, and some just need a simple disclosure added. If the user edits them into shape I'll be happy to undelete them.

Answer (score 19):

In general, if you observe cases similar to this one, I think this is a perfect use of a custom moderator flag. Particularly if it's not an isolated post, but a whole series that might continue if nothing is done about it, moderators are best equipped to handle the situation.

The custom flag lets you include a comment. Use it to explain in detail what you are seeing. I have done that in the past even if I was not completely certain that it was in fact spam, but it looked suspicious enough. The flags always came back as helpful. The flag text I used typically sounded something like this:

> This user has posted identical answers with the same link 7 times within the last 20 minutes. All of them were answers to old questions. I have not been able to find out if the user is associated with the tool they link to, so I'm not sure if this is spam. I think a moderator should look into this, and decide if the posts should be considered spam.