# Stack Overflow user with no other accounts

Tags: support, profile-page

I happened to look at [a user's profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3948753/ncomputers-org), and noted that although they have a reputation score they are listed as having 0 other accounts.

The user also does not have a Stack Exchange Network Profile, which should be located [here](https://stackexchange.com/users/4900171/ncomputers-org).

[image: User with no accounts]

I've looked around at a couple of other users, and they all have Stack Overflow listed under their account sections, so it should be there (this user is not a deleted user).

Here's an example of a low-rep user's account section as it would normally appear on Stack Overflow and Meta Stack Overflow:

[image: User with one account]

I got curious, so did a search: `"this user has no other accounts on the stack exchange network"`

The situation is not unique, but rare. I also found another user on CS50 who hasn't hit the search-engine data yet. The search gets one old hit (user now has three SE acconts) and another SO user with 0 accounts. There's an old Meta SE question about an issue affecting all, since resolved.

ncomputers.org now *does* have the Stack Exchange link on both their Meta and SO profiles, so changed from when the question was asked.

Comment: while he exists: http://stackoverflow.com/users/3948753/ncomputers-org

Comment: As I said, I checked other low-rep users and found three who only have SO accounts. They show as having one account. This user does not. Something is different.

Comment: @BillWoodger Can you post an example of one that shows the 1 account?

Comment: Here's another low-rep user picked at random. One account, SO only. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2932541/fortune

Comment: Something peculiar *is* going on here: this user does not have a Stack Exchange Network Profile, though s/he *does* have [a main site profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3948753/ncomputers-org).

Comment: @BillWoodger You might want to edit your question a bit to further explain what's up and show a screenshot of that second example. I was completely confused at first, and I think others were, as to what the issue was. :)

Comment: @Kendra I had prepared a second image then left it out, thinking the question said it all. It's been a long day.

Comment: An irony I notice is that 0 Accounts is pluralised.

Comment: @AstroCB Thanks. A 404-not found Panda. I love irony.

Comment: As far as I can imagine, there can be no user on SE anywhere with 0 accounts. There's an intrinsic contradiction.

Comment: @BillWoodger [Correct plural form of a zero quantified noun](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13073/correct-plural-form-of-a-zero-quantified-noun)

Comment: The account in question was accused of repeatedly posting commercial spam, it's likely that some action was taken against the account, resulting in this weirdness

Comment: @BillWoodger it means someone actually hand-coded the scenario where there is only one account, i.e. none of the Account(s) grievances.

Comment: I've been coming over this account and also issued a [meta question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271586/what-to-do-with-a-user-who-frequently-spams-so-with-useless-links-to-their-main) here. May be the main account is blocked meanwhile, but to see the meta account still active is strange.

Comment: @animuson I know it's correct, I was just surprised to see 1 Account and 0 Accounts, correctly done (not always so here) where 0 Accounts should not logically exist. In case I get myself stuck with that one, I'll qualify it with "on a site-Meta".

Comment: @Kendra Your first comment now has five votes, up from three. Perhaps that can be tidied away, since it is accurate only in a very marginal sense but people seem to believe it in general?

Comment: @BillWoodger See my answer; I cracked it ;).

Comment: @Compass More likely it's a `!= 1` and just a happy accident

Answer (score 14):

I did some experimentation by creating two new Stack Overflow accounts; one via Google and the other a Stack Exchange account.

I found that the [Stack Exchange account](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4239834/user4239834) has Stack Overflow listed in the 'Accounts' section:

[image]

However the [account registered via Google](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4239854/user4239854) ***does not***:

[image]

The Stack Overflow user with no other accounts simply registered via Google or Facebook as opposed to registering a Stack Exchange account. ***The account is also valid only for Stack Overflow and doesn't work on any other Stack Exchange site, but does show up on the 'Stack Exchange' statistics.***

I haven't tested this behaviour on other Stack Exchange sites as I don't want to give the moderators a hard time with 'duplicate accounts' (moderators should probably remove the <strike>two accounts</strike> one account I haven't removed but linked to here, or perhaps they'll be kept but locked for reference).

Comment: Thanks. That's interesting. However, I'm wondering if there is some further processing which occurs later. I'm sure there must be more than five people who have used google/facebook to register (me, for instance). Try the search I added to the question: your answer may relate to the three from CS50 (there's at least one more as well), but where are the hundreds/thousands of others who just poke in a password?

Comment: @BillWoodger Perhaps the system adds Stack Overflow when the same account registers under another Stack Exchange site? I'll try this out later when I've got more time.

Comment: Thanks. I'm just thinking that of thousands of 1rep users many will have just used google/facebook, asked, got answer/pounded, and fled. Each day. Yet they don't show on my search. I'm pretty sure this user, http://stackoverflow.com/users/3948678/isomarcte, earlier, didn't have the network profile icon. Now they do, but it produces just the 404-panda image.

Comment: Here's a new CS5 user, http://cs50.stackexchange.com/users/2983/bwhiting, perhaps exactly what you created. But I think they'll "change" over the coming days. We'll see.

Comment: Yes, the same search this morning seems to imply some sort of moving target. Four the same, two new ones (CS50 and Movies, both beta?) plus remaining ones which don't seem to have hit the search-data yet. Meta question(!) and two other users from yesterday have disappeared from the search.